# firefox moz, Web Transitions

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit, transition

I have the following:

```
.ui-dialog-body {
    position: relative; /* Needed for sliding left, right */
    min-height:60px;
    padding: .5em 1em;
}
.ui-dialog-body.slideLeft {
    left:-500px;
    -webkit-transition: left .5s linear;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
    -moz-transition-property: left;
    -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
}
```

When the user clicks an item which requires loading, the class slideLeft is added which slides the div out of view. This works great in webkit (safari, chrome) but not in FireFox 4 beta.

Any ideas why that is?

Comment: Could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) which shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `left: 0` in the first style rule so that the transition is from 0px to 500px (which can be interpolated) rather than auto to 500px (which can't).

(Also, there are differences between your -webkit-* declarations and your -moz-* declarations, but I don't think there need to be.)

Answer (score 0):

Put the declaration on the element, not the added class:

```
.ui-dialog-body {
    position: relative; /* Needed for sliding left, right */
    min-height:60px;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    -webkit-transition: left .5s linear;
    -moz-transition: left .5s linear;
    -ms-transition: left .5s linear;
    -o-transition: left .5s linear;
    transition: left .5s linear;
}

.ui-dialog-body.slideLeft {
    left:-500px;
}
```